# Segmented Control on each cell of a TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to set a segmented control on each cell of the tableView of my application, which could change the values of an array.

In my example, I'd like to set an Array with values "A", "A", "A", "A", all of them should be changed by selection on the segmented control...

I hope I'm clear... Thanks a lot !

(I'd like post an image but i'm a new user and by the way I'm not allowed to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually made an **UITableView** with SegmentedControl on each row, with action:

```
(IBAction)select:(id)sender {

NSIndexPath *indexPath =
[self.tableView indexPathForCell:(uneCell *)[[sender superview] superview]];
NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

[uneArray replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:((UISegmentedControl*) sender).selectedSegmentIndex]];

[self refresh];


}
```

Where uneCell is the class of the **UITableViewCell** and uneArray is an array containing the index value of the SegmentedControl for each cell.

Answer (score 1):

I am just going to put the basic idea here:

- Create a sub-class of UITableViewCell that will have your Segmented Control
- Add your data model on the cell so you are aware of the current value of your SegmentedControl
- When creating the cell, add the logic for the UISegmentedControl of the cell, like this:

> ```
> [segmentedControl addTarget:cell action:@selector(changeValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
> ```

- Add the method `changeValue:` to your cell.
- Inform your data source that the value for that cell has changed. (in this case you could use a singleton to hold your data source).